# Proper way to define function based on loop index?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I wanted to create a bunch of functions in a loop to connect for an event.
The relevant code is pretty much this:

```
for i in range(10):
    #Create function for current index
    tmp = lambda: self.do_something(i)
    #and connect event to the function
    event.connect(tmp)
```

Unexpectedly,(at least for me), when called - all functions act as if i = 9.
Tested the same code in ipython with just list comprehention and it behaves the same way:

```
l = [lambda:i for i in range(10)]
list(x() for x in l)
```

and the output is:

```
Out[15]: [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

What's the proper way to achieve the goal of creating 10 different functions this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a default argument:

```
event.connect(func, lambda i=i: self.do_something(i))
```

Since default arguments are evaluated at definition, you're set.